# Tampermonkey/greasemonkey youtube redirect script from /shorts/* to /watch?v=*

Tags: youtube, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

No idea how to code, but the title should explain what I'm after.

If I go to https://www.youtube.com/shorts/zUy4y2CqCV0 I would like to automatically be redirected to the full youtube player version which is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUy4y2CqCV0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

This here can do it:
https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/439993-youtube-shorts-redirect

The content of the script in case the link breaks.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Youtube shorts redirect
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.3
// @description  Youtuebe shorts > watch redirect
// @author       Fuim
// @match        *://*.youtube.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=youtube.com
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// @license      GNU GPLv2
// ==/UserScript==
var oldHref = document.location.href;
if (window.location.href.indexOf('youtube.com/shorts') > -1) {
    window.location.replace(window.location.toString().replace('/shorts/', '/watch?v='));
}
window.onload = function() {
    var bodyList = document.querySelector("body")
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            if (oldHref != document.location.href) {
                oldHref = document.location.href;
                console.log('location changed!');
                if (window.location.href.indexOf('youtube.com/shorts') > -1) {
                    window.location.replace(window.location.toString().replace('/shorts/', '/watch?v='));
                }
            }
        });
    });
    var config = {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    };
    observer.observe(bodyList, config);
};
```